# Matlab Programming - Deploying different size arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have a problem with matlab. There are two different sized vectors and i want to combine them in a matrix.

eg. a=[1 2 3 4]
    b=[5 6]

```
c=[1 2 3 4
   5 6 0 0]
```

Comment: Try this: c = [a;b 0 0]. Matlab does not allow arrays of different size to be concatenated, so we need to pad with some values.

Comment: Good but, if there  are more than 2 vectors? I want to combine them

Comment: Do you have a general rule for this? Why do you want to combine these vectors?

Comment: Please give the whole picture so we can come up with a general solution for this. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I want to use fuzzy c-means clustering in matlab. I'm using fcm function for it. The result stored in matrix. Every column has my answers and seperate them to assigning vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use padarray:

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
b = [5 6];
c = [7 8 9];

list = {b c};

[tmp,size_a]   = size(a);
[tmp,listSize] = size(list);

M = a;

for i = 1:listSize

    el = cell2mat(list(i));
    [tmp,size_b] = size(el);

    diff = size_a - size_b;
    el   = padarray(el, [0 diff], 'post')
    M    = [M; el];

end

M % show matrix
```

This should be enough to iterate over a list of arrays and build your matrix.